# Export the SVG only within artboard in illustator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

So I've added a text in Illustrator and I'm trying to cut in 2/3 - 1/3 proportions with artboards as in the picture below. I exported it as an SVG but when i open it with a browser it shows the full letters text in SVG. I expected it to only show the letters inside 01 Artboard or 02 Artboard.

Using only one artboard at a time doesn't help.
I've checked the Use Artboards option when exporting.

The problem is that I made it once with another word without any problems, then two days later I tried with another word (the one shown below) and now either it doesn't work anymore for some strange reason or I am doing something wrong and different from the last time.

[image: Illustrator view]

Comment: I just tried and had no issues with the Use Artboards option. Maybe try converting the text to outlines?

Comment: Still no luck. Another thing I've noticed is that if even a small part of the letter is in the artboard, it will include the whole letter in the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do not need to preserve editing the text for later, you can achieve what you are looking for by expanding the text, using divide from pathfinder, deleting the division areas you do not want, and then saving out the SVGs. See the images for step-by-step below:

1 — select the text and expand it using `object->expand`
[image: expand the text]

2 — create a shape that you will use to divide the expanded text. Note that I made my shape red so you can see the division, but if you want to save a step, then make it the same color as your text). With both the expanded text and the shape selected, divide them (use `window->pathfinder` to bring up the tool).
[image: create a shape that you can use to divide the text (note that I made the shape red so you can clearly see how it divides).]

3 — Delete the unwanted division areas (and recolor the text if you used a different color shape) before saving out your SVGs.
[image: Delete the unwanted division areas and save out your SVGs]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works. Even though it requires a bit more work to do, that way I learnt how to slice svgs.

Comment: Sorry that it's a bit more work, but I'm glad that this method works out for you!